# QtChart - C++ - Saving a chart which wasn't displayed

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I'm trying to save a chart to a file, in a QTextDocument in this example :

```
QTextDocument doc("Frame rate test\n");
QTextCursor cursor(&doc);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);

if (getTestFinishedStatus())
{
    QPixmap pix = _pFrameRateChart->grab(); //_pFrameRateChart is QChartView
    cursor.insertImage(pix.toImage());
}

QTextDocumentWriter docWriter;
docWriter.setFileName("framerate.odf");
docWriter.setFormat("ODF");
docWriter.write(&doc);
```

The problem is the result isn't same if I'm displaying the chart in an ui.
Here is the result when not displayed :

[image]

Here is the result when displayed :

[image]

Obviously I would like to have the second result even when I don't add the ChartView to a widget to display it on an ui.
I've tried resizing the QChartView, resizing the QChart, adding the Chart to a temporarly widget and QVBoxLayout then saving it, showing temporarly the QChartView before saving it etc... but didn't managed to get a good result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any easy way to this, so here's my solution, which is more like a workaround though :

```
QPixmap ChartView::getChartPixmap()
{
    QWidget* w = new QWidget; //creating a temporary widget, which will enable to display the chart

    w->resize(REPORT_IMAGE_WIDTH, REPORT_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    QVBoxLayout *vl;
    vl = new QVBoxLayout(w);
    vl->addWidget(this); //'this' being the QChartView

    w->show(); //showing the widget so it is resized and can be grabbed with the correct dimensions

    QTest::qWait(500); //we need to wait for a little for the graph to be drawn otherwise you'll still have the same size problem

    QPixmap pixmap = w->grab(); //retrieve the pixmap

    w->hide(); //hiding the widget

    return pixmap;
}
```

It's working but you'll have a small window opened with the graph for 500 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to render a QGraphivsView on a Pixmap, since QtCharts is based on QGraphivsView, I think this will also work.

Try to *render* the image instead of trying to grab the pixmap.

```
void Printer::putProfileImage(QRect profilePlaceholder, QRect viewPort, QPainter *painter, QGraphivsView* profile)
{
    int x = profilePlaceholder.x() - viewPort.x();
    int y = profilePlaceholder.y() - viewPort.y();
    QRect pos(x, y, profilePlaceholder.width(), profilePlaceholder.height());
    profile->render(painter, pos);

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same result with a large image but a little chart

Comment: updated the answer with some bit of code that I use on a real project.